# What is the difference between adding a dependency via libraryDependencies versus an sbt plugin?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am a Scala newbie trying to understand the nuances of the language and tooling. I'm looking through a sample at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-samples/tree/master/scala/scala-play2.4 that uses play and I notice that the play dependency is added like so:

`addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.6")`
*https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-samples/blob/master/scala/scala-play2.4/project/plugins.sbt*

However in various other SO posts I see the dependency being added to libraryDependencies like so:

`libraryDependencies ++= Seq("com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % "2.2.2")`
*https://stackoverflow.com/a/22215070/201657*

or

`libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.3.4"`
*https://stackoverflow.com/a/19438083/201657*

What is the difference, and what are the implications, of these two techniques of adding a dependency? TIA.

Comment: You should probably gain some understanding from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771269/what-is-the-difference-between-plugins-dependencies-modules-and-sub-projects-i

Broadly, plugins enhance sbt's functionality and dependencies are what you use in your project to write code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in linked SO answer, sbt-plugins are used to enhance build behaviour.

In case of `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.6")` the pluging is modifying your build's `libraryDependencies` by following [code](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/7c196b9d6fc1032cbd75aa729ba55a81d62fcaa3/dev-mode/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/sbt/PlaySettings.scala#L60). Thus the dependency management is done by the plugin.

If you choose to manage it yourself, you could use following without enabling the `com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin`.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % "2.4.6")
```

If you choose to use sbt to launch your play application with hot reload functionality, you should consider using the `sbt-plugin`. But if you don't care about it, just add `play` as `libraryDependencies`.

Comment: I do want hot reload so I’ll stick with the plugin